# How do I avoid duplicates in MySQL query result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script fetching rows from a MySQL query, however, some `serum` is displayed multiple times. I rather want each `serum` to be displayed once only.

```
<?php
$typeno = 0;
$categories = [];
$gettestcat = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from types where testid = '$id'");

while($gtc = mysqli_fetch_array($gettestcat)){
    $testid = $gtc['testtypeid'];
    $gettesttypename = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tests where id = '$testid'");
    $gtyn = mysqli_fetch_array($gettesttypename);

    if (!in_array($gtyn['sample_type'], $categories)) {
        $categories [] = $gtyn['sample_type'];
    }
}

$countcat = count($categories);
$gettesttypes = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from types where testid = '$id'");

while($gtt = mysqli_fetch_array($gettesttypes)){
    $testid = $gtt['testtypeid'];
    $gettesttypenames = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tests where id = '$testid'");
    $gtyns = mysqli_fetch_array($gettesttypenames);

    if ($gtyns['sample_type'] == 'Serum') {
        echo $gi['name'].' - '.$gtyns['test_name'].' - ';
    }
}
?>

<?php  ?>
<?php   
?>
```

[image]

I need to get it like shown on the image, the name shown only once.

[image]

Comment: Why are you making the same queries multiple times instead of reusing the results?

Comment: It looks really weird. I did not investigate deeper, however, it pretty sure could be done with a fairly simple join and/or group by (or even a simple select only).

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the names you output in an array. Then you check if the name exists or not in the array before echoing it.

```
// Initialize the array
$names = [];

while($gtt = mysqli_fetch_array($gettesttypes)){
    $testid = $gtt['testtypeid'];
    $gettesttypenames = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tests where id = '$testid'");
    $gtyns = mysqli_fetch_array($gettesttypenames);

    if ($gtyns['sample_type'] == 'Serum') {

        if (!array_key_exists($gi['name'], $names)) {
            // The name doesn't exist in the array, echo it:
            echo $gi['name'] . '-';

            // Put the name into the array so it won't be echoed again
            $names[$gi['name']] = true;
        }

        echo $gtyns['test_name'].' - ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use mysql, use `DISTINCT` keyword for unique results